# Django direct_cloud_upload No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-3.8

I am trying to use the library [**direct_cloud_upload**](https://github.com/koendewit/django-direct-cloud-upload) to upload directly a file to a **Google Cloud Storage Bucket** without going through my **cloudrun** (to bypass the 32Mb request limitation).

Unfortunately, I consistently have this error: **No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.** on the admin fontend when I try to upload a file, even though the file is sucessfully uploaded to the storage.

[image: No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form. error]

There is obviously something I am missing, here is my code:

**models.py**

```py
class AudioFileModel(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio/')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

**forms.py**

```py
from .models import AudioFileModel
from django import forms


from google.cloud.storage import Client
import direct_cloud_upload
import os
from direct_cloud_upload import CloudFileWidget

from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service-account-key.json'
)


client = Client(credentials=credentials)

gcs_bucket = client.get_bucket(os.environ.get("GS_BUCKET_NAME"))
ddcu_bucket_identifier = direct_cloud_upload.register_gcs_bucket(gcs_bucket)


class UploadAudioFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AudioFileModel
        fields = ('title', 'audio_file')
        widgets = {
            'audio_file': CloudFileWidget(
                bucket_identifier=ddcu_bucket_identifier,
                path_prefix="audio_file_new/",
            )
        }
        }
```

**urls.py**

```py
from .views import *
import direct_cloud_upload


urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('upload_audio_file.html', AudioFileUploadView, name='AudioFileUploadView'),
    path('direct_cloud_upload/', include(direct_cloud_upload.urlpatterns)),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
from .forms import UploadAudioFileForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def AudioFileUploadView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadAudioFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('The file is saved')
    else:
        form = UploadAudioFileForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, 'upload_audio_file.html', context)
```

I have no errors in the cloud run bug, I think this is a front end bug.

I use **python 3.8.6** with **django 3.1.6**

Comment: I don't think you need to write `views` for this as `direct_cloud_upload` library will take care of uploading the file. You just have to include the `direct_cloud_upload.urlpatterns` which I see is already added in the path.

Comment: You can remove the `path` for `AudioFileUploadView ` and try once. I think it should work then.

Comment: @Ejaz Same error unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the fiels in the model should have been a **CharField**.

**models.py**

```py
class AudioFileModel(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    audio_file = models.CharField(max_length=160)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```